# Who is Ranbi in the Shitta Mekubetzet?

Tags: rishonim, tractate-nedarim

Who is the רנב"י quoted by the [Shitta Mekubetzet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezalel_Ashkenazi) to Nedaarim (8a s.v. אמר רב גידל)?

Could it be [R. Nissim ben Yaakov Gaon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissim_ben_Jacob)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Shitta Mekubetzet,  רנב"י stands for R. Natan bar Yosef. He was a student of the Ramban, and wrote a commentary to an older work from the Ramban on the laws of vows.

Comment: Thank you very much; where could I find out more about this character or his commentary?